# Ordering of boolean values

Tags: c++, c, boolean, comparison-operators

Under C++ or `<stdbool.h>` from C99, how is the less-than operator `<` defined for boolean values?

Alternatively, explain the behaviour of this code:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <stdbool.h>
#endif
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    bool b = -1;
    if(b < true) {
        printf("b < true\n");
    }
    if(b < false) {
        printf("b < false\n");
    }
    if(true < false) {
        printf("true < false\n");
    }
    if(false < true) {
        printf("false < true\n");
    }
}
```

Under MSVC version 10, compiled as C++ code, GCC 4.6.3-ubuntu5 compiled as C code and G++ 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 compiled as C++ code, all you get is

```
false < true
```

That is, the following inequalities are all `false`:

```
(bool)-1 < true
(bool)-1 < false
true < false
```

And the following is `true`:

```
false < true
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In C++ (and I suspect in C as well), `bool`s compare exactly as if
`false` were `0` and `true` were `1`.  And if the type is `bool`, no
values other than `true` and `false` are possible.

When comparing `bool` to other numeric types, it will convert to `int`,
again with `false` converting to `0` and `true` converting to `1`.

**Edit:** Both C++ and `stdbool.h` in C99 also force boolean values to be either 0 (false) or 1 (true) - `bool b = -1;` sets the value of `b` to 1.  Since `1 < 1` and `1 < 0` are both false, the inequalities in the question are correct.

**Edit:** (by James) Except that the above edit isn't really correct, at
least for C++.  A `bool` doesn't have a value of 0 or 1, it has a value
of `false` or `true`.  It's only when it is promoted to `int` that the
conversion creates the values of `0` and `1`.

And as Konrad has pointed out, there is no conparison of `bool` values.
The "usual arithmetic conversions" occur for the comparison operators,
which means integral promotion on both of the operands, which means
`bool` converts to `int` (as does `char` or `short`... or an enum).

All of which is rather technical.  In practice, you can remember that
`false` < `true`, or you can consider `false` is 0 and `true` is 1,
whichever works best for you.  The only important thing to remember is
that a `bool` can have *no* other values.

(Interestingly, I don't think that the bit patterns of a `bool` are
imposed by the standard.  An implementation could use the bit patterns
`0x55` and `0xAA`, for example, as long as all conversions to an
integral type gave 0 and 1, conversion to `bool` always gave the
appropriate value, etc.  Including zero initialization of static
variables.)

And one final note: `bool b = -1;` sets `b` to `-1 != 0` (which is
`true`, not `1`, but of course, `true` will convert to `1` in any
numeric context.

Comment: Can you find where this is defined in the standard? I just looked and was unable to find it (I’m not even sure what to search for).

Comment: @Mansuro Irrelevant, James and I were talking about C++. But even for C nothing in this document states how a conversion `(bool) -1` is handled.

Comment: §4.5 Integral promotions.  "An rvalue of type `bool` can be converted to 
an rvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming
one."  (Note that a `bool` never has a value of `0` or `1`; only `false`
and `true`.  That's why I said "exactly _as if_.")  And §4.12 for the
conversions to `bool`.

Comment: Yes, but where does it define their ordering? EDIT: Duh, forget it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: There is no actual ordering on `bool`. As with many other operations, the value is promoted to `int` following the rules above, and then it two ints are compared.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Very good point.  My wording could have been a lot better, and taken this into account.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I did the same. I just made the promotion explicit due to Konrad's comment, so we should thank him for that. :)

Answer (score 5):

This makes perfect sense. The integral type => bool conversion is effectively `b = i != 0`. In order to do the `<` comparison it promotes the bool to int by the rule false=>0 and true=>1. In your first case `-1` will equate to true, and both will promote to 1 so it's false. Obviously 1 is never less than 0 for the second and third cases, while `0 < 1` in the last case.

Answer (score 3):

bool seems to be defined as a (signed) integer type, false being 0, zero being 1. This explains why true > false (1 > 0) is true.

Also, comparing -1 to an unsigned number makes -1 be cast to unsigned, and on your platform this causes an integer overflow, resulting UINT_MAX (or whichever type bool has been typedeffed to). This now explains why the following expressions were false:

```
((bool)-1) < true i. e. UINT_MAX < 1
((bool)-1) < false i. e. UINT_MAX < 0
true < false i. e. 1 < 0
```

Comment: Formally, `bool` is defined as a signed (not unsigned) integral type, even though the only values it can take (`true` and `false`) all have non-negative values.  And `((bool)-1)` isn't `UINT_MAX`, it's `1` when considered as an `int`.

Comment: bool is not unsigned int, it's defined as int  http://gel.sourceforge.net/examples/stdbool_8h-source.php

Comment: In C `_Bool` (as the underlying type behind `bool`) is defined as an unsigned integer type. All values different from `0` that are converted to `bool` result in the value `1`. So `(bool)-1` is always `1` and thus the `< true` and `< false` is always false.

Comment: @JamesKanze: That is the problem with questions that ask about C/C++ assuming that they are *similar enough*. In C99, the type of `_Bool` (`bool` is a macro that expands to `_Bool`) is unsigned.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas perfect point! (in Objective-C, there is `typedef unsigned char BOOL;`)

Comment: @H2CO3: I didn't, here's +1 to make up for it :)

Answer (score 3):

Boolean values are ordered such that `false` is smaller than `true`. According to the standard, a `bool` can only hold two values: `true` and `false`, so the conversions in `(bool)-1` should have yielded `true` (as all non-0 values when converted to bool are `true`). That is the behavior in clang and g++-4.7.

The actual comparison (I believe) is done on `int` after the `bool` is promoted, and it seems that the compilers you tested avoided the intermediate step of converting through bool and just promoted the actual `bool` value.

Answer (score 2):

operator > and < base on this:

```
true == (1)
false == (0)
```

this false:
    (bool)-1 < true
    (bool)-1 < false
because of rolling arithmetic in bool b = -1;

Answer (score 2):

For C++ just `false` < `true`

For C is more difficult to answer. I see

`typedef char _Bool;        /* For C compilers without _Bool */`  in my stdbool.h

Seems, that if compiler support `_Bool` , it works as in C++ and automatically converts to 0/1, but if not it should work as char and it'll be `b < true`, `b <  false` if char is signed

For me (int)(bool) -1 is 1 even in C, so `bool` is defined as not char

Comment: your compiler doesn't seem to be compliant to C99 or C11 if it really does this `typedef`. `_Bool` is an unsigned integer type that can hold the values `0` and `1` and such that all values different from `0` are converted to `1` as e.g in `(bool)-1`. (the later wouldn't work correctly with `char` as a substitute.) Since this is an integer type the ordering of the possible values is the same as for all integer types `0` is smaller than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explaination, I haven't checked with the standard though.
From your experiments it seems that the "<" operator is not defined for boolean values. What is compared is the unsigned ints that the booleans are converted to. In theory it could be possible that the standard doesn't guarantee that all "true" booleans are converted to the same value. And -1 is converted to the largest unsigned int.

As another experiment, the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout<< (((bool)1) == true) << "\n";
std::cout<< (((bool)2) == true) << "\n";
std::cout<< (((bool)0) == false) << "\n";
std::cout<< (((bool)1) == false) << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

prints 1 1 1 0

So any nonzero value is "true".