# Sorting vectors of objects by data members

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

Yes, I know this is a repeat question and I already know that the anwser im looking for is here:

[Sorting a vector of objects by a property of the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174115/sorting-a-vector-of-objects-by-a-property-of-the-object)

However I have problems converting this to my own code. I'm looking at this code snippet from the above question:

```
struct SortByX
{
    bool operator() const(MyClass const& L, MyClass const& R) {
        return L.x < R.x;
    }
};

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), SortByX();
```

What I do not understand is what is being represented by `MyClass const & L`, and  `MyClass const & R`. And I am not grasping how I can apply this to my code.

To give a bit more detail I am putting 3 sort methods into a wrapper class of a vector of objects that have parameters of (`string`, `double`, `double`, `double`, `bool`). And the over all goal is to sort the `vector` by the `string`, the `bool` and any one out of the 3 doubles.

This is the lastest version I have:

```
void StationVector::sortByGrade(int kindOfGas) {
struct SortByGrade {
    int kindOfGas;

    SortByGrade(int kindOfGas) :
            kindOfGas(kindOfGas) {
    }

    bool operator()(GasStation const &L, GasStation const & R) const {
        return L.getPrice(kindOfGas) < R.getPrice(kindOfGas);
    }
};

std::sort(localStations.begin(), localStations.end(),
        SortByGrade(kindOfGas));
}
```

the line `SortByGrade(kindOfGas))` gives me the following error:

no matching function for call to `sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, model::StationVector::sortByGrade(int)::SortByGrade)'

Comment: `MyClass` represents the type stored by your vector.

Comment: `MyClass` should be replaced by whatever kind of objects are stored in your vector.

Comment: What does the compiler say is the error? Don't leave us guessing!

Comment: The error was that a ; was out of place. which i don't think is the actual issue

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate how to put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You're going to need to provide enough code to reproduce this error (but, critically, no more) for us to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I do not understand is what is being represented by MyClass const & L, and MyClass const & R.

`L` and `R`, in this case are two items (instances of your class `MyClass`) from the container that are being compared, with `L` on the left of the less-than operator and `R` on the right. They are passed in by const-reference.

> And I am not grasping how I can apply this to my code.

In your own `bool operator() const(MyClass const& L, MyClass const& R)`, you need to compare the three data members you mention in your question, vitally remembering to apply [**strict weak ordering**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering). Return `true` if `L` is "less than" `R` and `false` otherwise.

---

Following updates to the question...

It looks like you wish to pass a variable into your [***functor***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses). You do this by creating a constructor, like this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (which [compiles here](http://ideone.com/JhNLFx#)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

namespace model {

struct GasStation
{
    double getprice(int kindOfGas) const
    {
        return kindOfGas;
    }
};

struct StationVector
{
    std::vector<GasStation> localStations;

    struct SortByGrade
    {
        int kindOfGas_;
        SortByGrade(int kindOfGas)
            :kindOfGas_(kindOfGas)
        {
        }

        bool operator() (GasStation const &L, GasStation const & R) const
        { 
            // You'll need other comparisons here, but this is a good start...
            return L.getprice(kindOfGas_) < R.getprice(kindOfGas_); 
        }
    };

    void sortByGrade(int kindOfGas) 
    {
        std::sort(localStations.begin(), localStations.end(), SortByGrade(kindOfGas));
    }
};

}

int main()
{
    model::StationVector sv;
    sv.sortByGrade(0);
}
```

Note: The `const` qualifier comes after the argument list and not after the method name.

Also, please don't put the entire method on one line, it makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: Im still not understanding how to implement the code properly. Can you show me an example

Comment: Trying the above example is getting an error stating

 "passing `const model::GasStation' as `this' argument of `double model::GasStation::getPrice(int)' discards qualifiers"

 I'm not sure what thats trying to tell me.

Comment: `double model::GasStation::getPrice(int)` should be declared `const` (unless it somehow modifies the state of the object, in which case it's not likely to be a good candidate to use in a comparator).

Comment: Meaning? I changed

 double GasStation::getPrice(int){

to

double const GasStation::getPrice(int){

That didn't change anything. Did i misunderstand what you were trying to say?

Comment: As I wrote earlier, "Note: The const qualifier comes after the argument list and not after the method name.". `double GasStation::getPrice(int) const`.

Comment: Ok thanks. I very new to C++ this is only my second attempt at it.
I finally got the struct code to work except now the actual sort call has an error saying "no matching function call...." is that a #include problem? right now im using <algorithm> do I need something else to make it recognize the call?

Comment: It depends on what it says is missing and where it is declared!

Comment: It delclared it the header file of the class and here is the whole error message `no matching function for call to sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<model::GasStation*, std::vector<model::GasStation, std::allocator<model::GasStation> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<model::GasStation*, std::vector<model::GasStation, std::allocator<model::GasStation> > >, model::StationVector::sortByGrade(int)::SortByGrade)`

Comment: Can you please paste the latest version of your `sortByGrade(int)` method as an addition to your question. I cannot debug like this.

Comment: Well crap. I all i had to do for awhile now is move the struct out of the method I was trying to use it in. I got it working now.
 Again thank you for the help. I doubt I would have figured any of this out by myself.

Comment: Moving the `struct` out of the method will make it easier to reuse and to test. It may also prevent "shadowing" variables. Glad I've helped you but ***don't forget the strict weak ordering***.

Comment: Actually one last thing on that if when im dealing with bools I know i  can't say bool1 < bool2. But really It dose not matter if the false or the true comes first so can't I just say `return bool1`? As long as it sorts all of one the all of the other then its fine. Will that do that?

Comment: [You *can* compare `bool`s with `<`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951729/ordering-of-boolean-values)! And **to ensure strict weak ordering, it does matter**, so you will probably need a comparison like: `if (L.loyalty_card != R.loyalty_card) return L.loyalty_card < R.loyalty_card;` (just making up a `bool` value there)!

Comment: I just tried that and got an error. But will the way I suggested work?
(By the way I'm programming blind here, because I can't run/test any code. Something somewhere on my comp is messed up and i don't have time to try to fix it)

Comment: The best advice I can give at this time is stop programming until you have fixed your environment and you can run and test your code. Here is an example of sorting including the `bool` values: http://ideone.com/lmyqOi

Answer (score 2):

`SortByX` is a binary predicate functor. Binary predicate means it takes two arguments and returns a boolean. Functor means it's instances are callable. For example:

```
MyClass a = ....;
MyClass b = ....;
SortByX comp;
bool flag = comp(a,b); // call this SortByX instance with two MyClass instances
```

Now, `std::sort` will internally use a copy of the instance of `SortByX` that you pass it in order to perform the comparisons between the elements of a `std::vector<MyClass>` needed to sort that vector.

```
std::vector<MyClass> v;
// fill the vector with MyClass objects
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), SortByX()); // sort the vector using a SortByX instance for comparisons
```

Note: for this to work, the binary predicate must implement [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html).

Comment: So If im reading this correctly This explains how SortByX works but now how to implement it.

Comment: @Nood the `SortByX` implementation that you posted shows you exactly how this thing can be implemented. Looking at your edit, it looks like you got it.